# How to add "Delivery Receipt Requested" attribute to email entity?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'd like to add the deliveryreceiptrequested attribute to the email entity form. It's not shown on the list of fields and I don't see on the standard email form. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the *deliveryreceiptrequested* field is only populated thru the Outlook Client, and is only used by Outlook itself. This field is only in the Email Entity for information purpose and is not handled by CRM itself.

Also, the only way I know that this attribute is used, is thru the Outlook Client... maybe this will be handled in CRM 5?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I hope it is handled in CRM 5